# How many functions satisfy $f_7(x)=x$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Define a function $f(x):=4x(1-x)$. How many $x$ in $[0,1]$ satisfy $$f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x)))))))=x$$

I tried to do it by plugging in $x=\frac{1}{y}$ considering $x\in (0,1]$ and then proceed by considering the $x=0$ case separately. But I got to nowhere.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be continuous?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, the Question has been edited.

Comment: Solve $f(x)=x$ for two solutions.

Comment: Yes, $0$ and $1$ I believe.

Comment: @Arthur brilliant solution, this gives $0$ and $3/4$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar May I know how?

Comment: if $f(x)=x$ this implies $f(f(x))=f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x = (1-\cos(t))/2$, $f(x) = (1 - \cos(2t))/2$.
Thus we need
  $\cos(t) = \cos(128 t)$, which says $128 t = \pm t + 2 n \pi$ for some integer $n$, i.e. $t = \frac{2n\pi}{127}$ or $t = \frac{2n\pi}{129}$.
All values of $x$ are obtained with $t$ in $[0,\pi]$, and thus $t = \frac{2n\pi}{127}$ for $0 \le n \le 63$ or $t = \frac{2n \pi}{129}$ for $0 \le n \le 64$.  $t=0$ is common to both, so there are $128$ solutions.

Comment: Sir, that's a great substitution. Also, I think this works welll: $x=\sin^2(\theta)\implies f(\theta)=4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=sin^2(2\theta)$.